# How to add Bold or Italic (INLINE) using Jade? *Like markdown

Tags: html, pug, markdown

There is some way to make strong some words **in the same code line** using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) to generate the HTML?

I try to use [markdown code](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), like this. But isn't working:

```html
p Here are my **strong words** in my sentence!
```

An unique solution that I found ([here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/)) was:

```html
p Here are my <strong>strong words</strong> in my sentence!
```

There any other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can simply do:

```
p Here is my #[strong strong words] in my sentence!
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 21):

For Pug or Jade, you need to wrap the element in a paragraph, and use the `|` for line continuation.

```
p
  strong This Starts out strong 
  |  but finishes out not 
  i  quite 
  |  as bold.
```

Which will look like:

**This starts out strong** but finishes out not *quite* as bold.

EDIT:  As noted in the comments, you need an additional whitespace before each component, as pug doesn't add spaces.  The above will render out as:

```
<p><strong>This Starts out strong </strong> but finishes out not <i> quite </i> as bold.</p>
```

Comment: Except, that's not how it renders. Pug doesn't add white space in-between each of your lines. (e.g. This Starts out strongbut finishes out notquiteas bold.)

Comment: Correct. You need to remember to add the `&nbsp;` at the end of the first line (`&nbsp;` == "non-breaking space")

Answer (score 3):

You can use a span tag with style attribute (or CSS class).

`p Here is my&nbsp;
  span(style='font-weight:bold') strong words 
  &nbsp;in my sentence!`

Or you can do the same formatting (add line break and indent) with strong tags.

`p Here is my&nbsp;
  strong strong words 
  &nbsp;in my sentence!`

Comment: Whilst this solution works it produces this warning `Warning: missing space before text for line X of jade file`. Any way this can be avoided?

Comment: 'p Here is my 
 strong strong words
 |  in my sentence!'

Comment: `p Here is my(space)
 strong strong words
 |(space)(space)in my sentence!`
Try this code, @Tim